# External Driver unallocated, after using R pi

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi

Yesterday, I was using Raspberry Pi Model B Vi.2. Everything was working fine but today when I switch on my laptop it was showing me this.
[image: My external driver partitions are gone!!]

[image: Whole of my external drive becomes unallocated]

My external driver partitions are gone!! and space in driver becomes unallocated and Raspberry pi boot drive is still visible even Raspberry pi is unplugged.

I tried to find it on internet but I was unable to find the solution to my problem.
Please help me to get my partitions back without losing any data?
Thank you in advance